# Как к записи в wordpress добавить заданное «произвольное» поле, т.е. с закреплённым именем?

Tags: php, wordpress

Т.е. если по умолчанию в произвольных полях добавляешь и имя, и значение, то надо чтобы было просто два поля с заданными именами (например, "город" и "время") и можно было бы вносить только значение.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно, то плагин advanced custom fields

Comment: Непонятно. Вы хотите, чтобы у всех записей присутствовало два поля - "город" и "время"?

Comment: @KAGGDesign по сути да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте следующий код в functions.php:

```
function my_the_post_action( $post ) {
    global $post;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( is_admin() && $screen->base == 'post' && get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $city = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'city');
        if (!$city) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', 'Moscow' );
        }
        $time = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'time');
        if (!$time) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'time', '00:00' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_the_post_action' );
```

Он срабатывает при создании новой записи или редактировании существующей в админ-панели. Производится проверка, существуют ли у записи указанные произвольные поля. Если нет, они создаются со значениями по умолчанию Moscow и 00:00. Можно вместо этих значений поставить любые другие или пустые строки.